# Determining how many cells are visible from Viewshed using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, viewshed

Using the Viewshed plugin for QGIS (2.16.3) how can I establish how many cells are visible or not from the output Raster?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What have you tried?

Comment: Try the QGIS Viewshed plugin... there are several tutorials and videos out there that can show you how to use them...

Comment: Sadly I cannot see these, hence the question.